# radListview telerik accessing object on server side binding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, telerik

I have a object datasource for a telerik listview and on the onitemcreated method I want to be able to pull out that current object that it is on. can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the data object in `OnItemCreated` because that occurs before any data binding occurs.  Instead, you should do you processing in `OnItemDataBound`.  You can use logic like this:

```cs
var listDataItem = e.Item as RadListViewDataItem;
if (listDataItem != null)
{
    var theData = listDataItem.DataItem;
    //...
}
```

Telerik has a [page in their documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listview-differences-between-itemcreated-itemdatabound-events.html) specifically addressing the differences between the `ItemCreated` and `ItemDataBound` events.  Here is a snippet of that:

> **ItemCreated** is fired *before* the item is data-bound. Thus no data
>   is still in the listview item or the controls nested inside it. In
>   **ItemDataBound** all is available.